# how to display double quotes

Tags: cat

bash version: bash-5.0.7

double quotes disappeared

```
[root@cander ~]# cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

cat > test.conf << EOF
AA=${one:-["one","two"]}
EOF
[root@cander ~]# sh test.sh 
[root@cander ~]# cat test.conf 
AA=[one,two]
```

use \ was ineffective

```
[root@cander ~]# cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

cat > test.conf << EOF
AA=${one:-[\"one\",\"two\"]}
EOF
[root@cander ~]# sh test.sh 
[root@cander ~]# cat test.conf
AA=[\"one\",\"two\"]
```

expect content

```
AA=["one","two"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Quote processing inside expansions is weird.

This does what you want...

```
$ echo "${one:-["\"one\"","\"two\""]}"
["one","two"]
```

But it's different inside a here-doc...

```
$ cat <<EOF
> ${one:-["\"one\"","\"two\""]}
> EOF
[\"one\",\"two\"]
```

It's probably easiest to put the default value in a variable:

```
$ def_one='["one","two"]'
$ cat <<EOF
> ${one:-$def_one}
> EOF
["one","two"]
```

Answer (score 1):

May you try that  syntax :

```
admin@srv-web:~$ cat test.sh

#!/bin/bash 
cat > test.conf << 'EOF' 
AA=${one:-["one","two"]} 
EOF
```

and the result is:

```
administrateur@srv-web:~$ ./test.sh ; cat test.conf
AA=${one:-["one","two"]}
```

Comment: Note that the question has been updated.